# mongodb add condition after get sum of fileds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have two tables in mongo db like below

tabel inventories:

| id | count | productId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |

table products:

| id | title | inventoryIds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | test | [0,2] |
| 1 | test 1 | [1,3] |

i want write a query for table products with this condition ==>
if sum of count in inventories table for one products greater than zero return all data with this condition at products table
else return all data in products

output i want :

Products

| id | title | inventoryIds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | test | [0,2] |

because productId = 0 have 14 count in inventories but productId = 1 have zero count in inventories!

thank you for help me

Comment: A JSON representation of your desired example output *documents* would be helpful.  Some output *documents* showing with and without the condition being met would be super helpful.

Comment: update my tables and add result i want

Comment: FYI, to avoid getting questions downvoted, or possibly closed, in SO, it's best to include some code to show an attempt.  The code may even help clarify the question.  For `mongodb` questions, it's better to show your sample collections/documents in JSON so readers/answerers won't need to convert it to attempt a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to return *documents* from the `products` *collection* given your condition and example.

```js
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "inventories",
      "localField": "inventories",
      "foreignField": "productId",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "sum": {
              "$sum": "$count"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "inventorySum"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "inventorySum.sum": {
        "$gt": 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "_id",
      "inventorySum"
    ]
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H2vaVwn3TCu).

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "inventories": [
      0,
      2
    ],
    "title": "test"
  }
]
```